# Using Chrome Driver with Selenium 2

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to use Chrome Drive to execute some of my tests, which are working perfectly with Firefox, but I'm not being able to execute them, I'm already verified the requirements, which are the location of Chrome, Version 12 or higher, and things like that, but anyway still not working correctly, the way to call the driver is:

```
WebDriver fd = new ChromeDriver();
fd.get("url");
```

and then searching some elements, but nothing is working, the error message is:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Couldn't locate Chrome.  Set
>   webdriver.chrome.bin System info:
>   os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86',
>   os.version: '5.1', java.version:
>   '1.6.0_18' Driver info:
>   driver.version: ChromeDriver  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeBinary.getChromeBinaryLocation(ChromeBinary.java:220)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeBinary.getCommandline(ChromeBinary.java:121)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeBinary.prepareProcess(ChromeBinary.java:67)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeBinary.start(ChromeBinary.java:109)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeCommandExecutor.start(ChromeCommandExecutor.java:373)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startClient(ChromeDriver.java:65)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:85)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:25)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:43)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:53)
>     at
>   equifax.qa.test.NewTests.access.main(access.java:11)

Please if anyone can help me would be great.

Comment: This stacktrace is from an older version of Selenium, before the ChromeDriver rewrite. Some of the classes shown no longer exists. The advice given below assumes you're on a newer version.

Comment: Do you know how to do this from Python? When I use Firefox I do the following: If there a python module for chrome?

from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class Untitled(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://mysite.com/")
        self.selenium.start()

Comment: Figured out my question above.  I can replace "*chrome" with   *firefox,   *mock,  *firefoxproxy,  *pifirefox,  *chrome,  *iexploreproxy,  *iexplore,  *firefox3,  *safariproxy,  *googlechrome,  *konqueror,  *firefox2,  *safari,  *piiexplore,  *firefoxchrome,  *opera,  *iehta,  *custom

Comment: I am using groovy? How to give this for groovy?

Comment: I have the same issue, actually I posted my question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436156/selenium-possible-upgrade-issue I am very confused ... Is it the problem with the Selenium, chromedriver or what?

Answer (score 44):

I was able to get this to work by launching the selenium server like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe
```

(Running Windows 7 64bit, Chrome 12, selenium server rc2)

Comment: +1 I tried to use HtmlUnit and it works fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436156/have-chromedriver-features-been-deprecated I think that the problem lies in the ChromeDriver

Answer (score 14):

Download the ChromeDriver.exe from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list then add the system property like so:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "...\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Hi I am curious how is this driver different from org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver?

Comment: ChromeDriver uses the chromedriver.exe to interact with Chrome. org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is simply the language binding which allows you to interface with chromedriver.exe which in turn interacts with the actual browser.

Comment: +1 If this is the case then why should we set the system property? We are not setting this for FireFox!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure whether this is the reason but ChromeDriver.exe is developed by Google developers instead of the WebDriver/Selenium team so at a guess I would think it's integration issues. It makes it easier to develop the 2 projects concurrently maybe ? Just a guess !

Comment: That property should be "webdriver.chrome.driver" (at least in selenium 2.0rc3)

Comment: How does one set this property if you're using the python bindings?

Comment: I am using groovy.. How to set the property.. and run.. Can you give the steps completely?

Answer (score 5):

Use this for Chrome

[Step-1 Download Chrome driver from location](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

Step-2 Use Testng Framework

```
@BeforeClass

public void setUp() throws Exception

{ 

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://Work-Selenium//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    baseUrl = "http://google.com";

    driver.get(baseUrl);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just download the **chromedriver_win32_13.0.775.0.zip** and **selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc3.jar** from [http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list][1]

Unzip the chromedriver_win32_13.0.775.0.zip into a folder, Eg. C:/drivers/chrome/, so that the chromedriver.exe is located at C:/drivers/chrome/chromedriver.exe.

Register the node against the hub on port 6668 (for example)

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc3.jar -role webdriver -hub http://hubUrlHostname:4444/grid/register -port 6668 -browser "browserName=chrome,version=13.0,platform=windows" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\drivers\chrome\chromedriver.exe
```

If you access to

> http://hubUrlHostname:4444/grid/console

you should see the Chrome driver registered.

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure that you have downloaded the Chrome driver from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list and placed it in your `PATH`?

have a look at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver for more details

Comment: Question, why do we have to use a prompt window to run our tests, Selenium 2 doesn't provide this feature already?

Comment: You don't need to run it. That's just one way of using it which can be useful for when connecting to remote instances. Doing it locally you may as well just set the system property and let WebDriver take care of the launching, etc.

Comment: Hi I am curious how is this driver different from org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the capabilities to point to the binary of the browser to be launched.

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

For ex:- Chromium Browser(33.0.1729.0 )works fine with ChromeDriver 2.7 and not the with the older ones.

You can choose from all the chromedriver version available from the link below:- http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

So try to use the browser version supported by the chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven Project. Follow the below steps

1. Download the latest chromedriver.exe from this link.
2. Create a drivers folder in test. It should look like this `src/test/resources/drivers`
3. Move the chromedriver.exe to the above path in step 2
4. Use the below code for before creating chrome driver object

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("drivers/chromedriver.exe").getFile());`