# Chrome Driver for Windows 8 64 bit

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium and writing my test cases only for firefox. I wish to write it also for Chrome driver. But where should I download for Widows 8 64 bit.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376925/using-chrome-driver-with-selenium-2)...Maybe that can help you.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried with 32-bit Windows ChromeDriver [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.3/)? What's wrong with it? If there are any errors, post full exception please.

As far as I know, there isn't a 64-bit Chrome on Windows yet (see [this ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8606)), as a result, there is no ChromeDriver for 64-bit Windows.

Here 32/64 bit are in term of the browsers' architecture, not the OS. Please check if your Chrome 32-bit or not, if it's 32-bit, download the 32-bit ChromeDriver.